# Get at entire web page contents using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to load the entire contents of a page into a javascript variable? (the page is not properly formatted HTML.) Ie store the page contents as a string in a variable. It only needs to work with Firefox.

I have some javascript running in one firefox tab that accesses the content of a page in another tab (the target window). Normally the content of the target is an HTML page so I can get at its content like this...

```
targetWindowName.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML;
```

However I have come across a page that is not in proper HTML and so the above doesnt work.

(The actual content of this awkward page is JSON. I know this would be best loaded up with AJAX or something but I have a framework already setup to process HTML pages and it would be very handy if I can treat this particular (one off) page just like a regular HTML page.)
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use AJAX? AJAX does not necessarily mean that it parses JSON. You can just load the raw contents into a variable.

Comment: @pimvbd. It would be best done like this if I was starting from scratch. But its an issue of project timescales and fitting this in with the rest of the code. I already have a framework set up to deal with normal HTML pages. It does much more than just access the pages content and so it will be very ackward at this stage in teh project to rewrite just for this one special case.

Comment: use html encode before assigning to JavaScript variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you can use:

```
win.document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Cant believe it was so simple. (I hadnt realized that after Firefox loads the page it adds tags round the page content if they are missing).

Answer (score 0):

Read the file into a variable.  Like you would any text file.

So, Page "A" has code that goes out and gets the HTML page contents and loads it into a variable.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I 'Read the file into a variable'? This is the bit I can figure out how to do in javascript.